# How to darken an image

Tags: javascript

I want to darken an image, but it isn't fully black in the end, because I can see the image some extent. I want to use vanilla JS only (no jQuery).

```js
var element = document.getElementById("img");
var colorArr = ["#fff","#ddd","#bbb","#999","#777","#555","#333","#000",];

var counter = 0;
var j=0;
var i = setInterval(function(){
    if(j < colorArr.length){
      element.style.backgroundColor = colorArr[j];
      j++;
    }  
  
    counter++;
    if(counter === 8) {
        clearInterval(i);
    }
}, 250);
```

```css
div.darken img {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <body>
 
  <div class="darken">    
     <img id="img" 
            src="http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/linked/astrid_avatar2.png" />
  </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should put your code in your post. This ensures that if someone else is looking for an answer to a similar question, or the same question, they can find it!

Comment: I have 3 different files (html, css, js), thatswhy I don't know how to put in the codes

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a second element above your `<img>` tag position it absolutely with a width and height that is the same as the image, and target that in your `element` variable in your code.

```js
var element = document.getElementById("overlay");
var colorArr = ["#fff","#ddd","#bbb","#999","#777","#555","#333","#000",];

var counter = 0;
var j=0;
var i = setInterval(function(){
    if(j < colorArr.length){
      element.style.backgroundColor = colorArr[j];
      j++;
    }  
  
    counter++;
    if(counter === 8) {
        clearInterval(i);
    }
}, 250);
```

```css
#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay"></div>
   <img id="img" src="http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/linked/astrid_avatar2.png" />
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I can see the image some extent at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Draw another rect with high transparency to cover image and slowly increase its opacity

Answer (score 0):

Despite you asked 4 years ago but after testing your sample code, and I couldn't see the image in the end, here is a small fix to your original code that guarantees the image cannot be seen when the loop ends:

```js
function darkenImage() {
  var element = document.getElementById("img");
  if (element.stop) return;
  var colorArr = ["#eee","#ccc","#aaa","#888","#666","#444","#222"];
  element.counter=0;
  var i = setInterval(function() {
    if (element.counter<colorArr.length) {
      element.style.backgroundColor = colorArr[element.counter];
      element.counter++;
    } else {
      clearInterval(i);
      element.width=element.offsetWidth;
      element.height=element.offsetHeight;
       element.src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAAAAAA6fptVAAAACklEQVQI12NgAAAAAgAB4iG8MwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==";
      element.stop=true;
    }
  }, 250);
}
```

```css
div.darken img {
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="darken">    
    <img id="img" src="http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/linked/astrid_avatar2.png" onload="darkenImage();"/>
</div>
```

I changed the color array so it doesn't feel at the end that the bgcolor jump is too big. Also I removed the initial value #fff and the last value #000 because they are not needed. Another change was that there were unnecesary variables and I put the counter as a property of the image element.

Finally instead of setting the background color to #000 I replaced the image with a single black dot base64 image.

If you can see your image in the end, I can only assume it is something in your screen or in your eyes that keeps cache/memory of the original image, because it was replaced completely.

Some final observations:

- The css with white background and the div around the image are unnecesary in the example but I kept them because you might have another use for it.
- For this to work properly the image must have only two colors, black for viewable pixels and transparent color for background. Additional changes must be done for an opaque image using opacity.